How to get multiple promises before running a final function or code in Javascript?
I'm new to Javascript promises and I'm trying to hit two API endpoints before running some Javascript.  My expectation was that the console output would be:
GET ConfigData Now... 
hello 
GET Resales Now... 
world
Finished here too...
Finished

Instead the Finished console log appears to never reached nor is the "Finished here too..." from the allDone() function.


function getConfigData() {
  console.log('GET ConfigData Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("hello");
  });
}

function getResales() {
  console.log('GET Resales Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("world");
  });
}

function allDone() {
  console.log('allDone Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Finished");
  });
}

async function getData() {
  await Promise.allSettled([getConfigData(), getResales()]);
  console.log(config);
  console.log(fullResales);
  await Promise.allSettled([allDone()]);
  console.log('Finished here too..');
}

getData()




By the looks of things you're also trying to log some things that don't exist (at least in the context of the code you've presented) so you'll get an error (console.log(config), for example).

Your code is using async / await, and for some random reason you change to using the promise constructor return new Promise((resolve) => { that you didn't resolve, an error that you wouldn't have done sticking to async / await.

You're not calling resolve, so the promises won't ever resolve.


function getConfigData() {
  console.log('GET ConfigData Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("hello");
  });
}

function getResales() {
  console.log('GET Resales Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("world");
  });
}

function allDone() {
  console.log('allDone Now...');
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve("Finished");
  });
}

async function getData() {
  console.log(await Promise.all([getConfigData(), getResales()]));
  console.log(await Promise.all([allDone()]));
  console.log('Finished here too..');
}

getData()



